# Force Non-SSL (http) on particular page and SSL on all other pages by .htaccess

Tags: http, zend-framework, ssl, https

I'm using Zend-Framework and below are the code of my htaccess.

```
rewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mysite.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co/$1 [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now I want to force http on mysite.co/news/* and https on all other pages. So how can i apply rule?

Comment: Just to point out that, by the time the client is in a position to get this redirection from `https://` to `http://`, it has already made an HTTPS request, hence the handshake (the "expensive" part of SSL/TLS) has already happened. Not sure you'll get the optimisation you're trying to achieve after this, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your controller and action and put this code into that condition, for that you can use bootstrap of zend framework.

like:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') {
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit();
}
```

Or you can use this bootstrap method

```
protected function _initForceSSL() {
    if($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == '443') {
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There exists the `isSecure()` function that lets you know if it is a **https** request (**true**) or **http** (**false**).
You can try to go through a plugin like this to redirect your query:

```
class Application_Plugin_SSL extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

    public function dispatchLoopStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){

      if (!$request->isSecure()){ // -> not https

            $request->setModuleName('yourmodule')
                    ->setControllerName('yourcontrolle')
                    ->setActionName('youraction')
                    ->setDispatched(true) ;
      }
    }
}
```